# Searching duplicates in real time while user is filling a UserForm, VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, database, duplicates, real-time

I'm facing a problem. I'm actually using this to check if a duplicate exists in my table :

```vb
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Me.txtCompanyName.Value, ws.ListObjects("Companies").ListColumns("company_name").Range, 0)) Then

   MsgBox "A company is already registered with this name"
```

This code is executed on a button click.

I'm wondering if there's a way to check in real time if duplicate exists in my table while user is typing better than waiting for him to click the button as we can see on some web forms. I tried to use AfterUpdate on `Me.txtCompanyName` but it's not really real time.

Thanks for your answers any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: The [`KeyUp` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keydown-keyup-events) is likely what you're going to want to listen to.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about this event thanks :D. May I bother you a bit if I struggle using it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ashleedawg said in the comments I used the `KeyUp` event to figure out.

Here is the answer to my question if it can be useful to someone else.

```
Private Sub myText_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim srch As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("myWorksheet")
        
    iRow = ws.Range("B1", ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    If Me.txtRaisonSociale.Value <> "" Then
    
        For i = 2 To iRow
        
            srch = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
            
            If InStr(srch, Trim(ModuleFonctions.setRegexRS(Me.myText.Value))) > 0 Then
                str = str + srch + Chr(13) & Chr(10)
            End If
            
        Next i
        Me.lblInfo.Caption = "Duplicate(s) found :" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & str
    
    Else
        Me.lblInfo.Caption = ""
    End If
        
End Sub
```

I build a string in a list with all duplicates found. then I set the string as a label caption.